# CALayer addAnimation:forKey: animates every property set before

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer, catransition

So, I've got a CALayer from a UITableView instance. I first want to set a couple properties like the backgroundColor. Afterwards I add an animation that is supposed to make the reloading (-reloadData) look nicer. However, the CATransition I'm adding also animates the backgroundColor I set before. I guess I'm missing something real basic here but I really don't get what.

Here's my code:

```
    self.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.backgroundColor = nil;
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = nil;
```

I want the UITableView to be green immediately.

Here's the transition:

```
CATransition* swapAnimation = [CATransition animation];
            swapAnimation.type = kCATransitionPush;
            swapAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionTypeFromUITableViewRowAnimation(animation);
            swapAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            swapAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
            swapAnimation.duration = 5.0f;
            swapAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
            [self.layer addAnimation:swapAnimation forKey:@"UITableViewReloadDataAnimationKey"];
```

When I'm running this, the UITableView keeps its original backgroundColor, the green (which is actually shining through the now transparent UITableView) slides in from the top/bottom with the cells.
It's code from a category explaining the self.layer calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to wrap the background color setter in an explicit `CATransaction`, because it's not getting flushed until after you add the animation.

Like so:

```
[CATransaction begin];
// set background
[CATransaction flush];
[CATransaction commit];
```